# LINQ - Not returning the same value as SQL Server

Tags: c#, .net, sql, linq, entity-framework

I have a really weird issue.

I have this query:

```
var systemAppEntityViewModelFieldCustom_SecurityByUserList = (from t in coreEntityModel.SystemAppEntityViewModelFieldCustom_SecurityByUser
                where (t.SystemAppUserID == CurrentSystemAppUser.SystemAppUserID)
                    && (t.SystemCultureID == CurrentSystemAppUser.SystemCultureID)
                select t).ToList();
```

Producing these values for the field "CustomFilterID":

[image]

As you can see, "CustomFilterID" = 1 for all 4 items, but when i check SQLProfiler and a run the result query in SQLServer, i get this:

[image]

A variation of "CustomFilterID" = 1 AND 2.

Any idea why LINQ will produce all 4 items with a "CustomFilterID" = 1?

Comment: Which one is the right one?

Comment: @FrancescoDeLisi `SQL` results.

Comment: I have had this problem when the primary key on the model is not setup correctly, check that first.

Comment: Can you list the values of coreEntityModel.SystemAppEntityViewModelFieldCustom_SecurityByUser? It looks weird.

Comment: Perhaps you need to refresh your context?

Comment: Are you selecting from a **view** in SQL Server?

Comment: @JensKloster It is a brand new context...

Comment: @marc_s Yes Marc, it is it a View.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the issue. My `View` was not selecting the `PK` column of the table and by adding the `PK` column of the table to the select list of the `View`, it produced the correct results.

Comment: That's exactly one of the "thorny" issues with selecting from views - even if you don't want to display it, you need to include the underlying table's PK to make EF work properly with views